# Как внедрить установку Mssql в внутрь Msi расширения InstallerProjects?

Tags: c#, sql-server, msi

Есть проект сделанный через расширение VS InstallerProjects, в внутрь которого вставляется установщик Mssql. Однако установщик ловит ошибку, что у него нету доступа к отладке:

The account that is running SQL Server Setup does not have one or all of the following rights: the right to back up files and directories, the right to manage auditing and the security log and the right to debug programs. To continue, use an account with both of these rights.

И не важно через CustomAction или напрямик подзывая данный файл, как действие.

В инете советы есть, но они требуют прямого вмешательства в пк юзера. Идей к сожалению уже нет, буду рад предложениям.

Есть ли вообще возможность сделать в данном расширении ?

Comment: вы установщик с правами админа вызываете?

Comment: @tym32167 Да, вызывали процесс через .Verb = "RunAS"; 
А также сам Msi установщик запускается с правами админа по умолчанию